# How to create a PyEDA boolean expression using a string containing a boolean expression?

Tags: python, parsing, boolean-logic, boolean-expression, pyeda

I am obtaining a boolean expression in the form of `( (A & B) | (C & ~D) )` from the frontend. I need to convert this into a boolean expression that can be solved by PyEDA. There are two steps to be done to write a boolean expression in PyEDA.

1. Create boolean variables A,B,C,D using `A,B,C,D = map(exprvar, "abcd") - This becomes a problem when number of boolean variables are dynamic` or `A = exprvars("a", 4) - solves the dynamic variable issue but need to convert letters in the equation to A[0],A[1]...`.
2. Write the expression as `( (A & B) | (C & ~D) )`.

The following approach was tried out. boolean_exp represents the boolean expression string and num_variables represent the number of variables in the string.

```
def parse_boolean_expression(boolean_exp,num_variables):
    count = 0
    boolean_exp_list = list(boolean_exp)
    for index,char in enumerate(boolean_exp_list):
        if char.isalpha():
            boolean_exp_list[index] = "Z[{}]".format(count)
            count += 1
    final_bool_exp = "".join(boolean_exp_list)

    Z = exprvars("z", num_variables)
    expression = final_bool_exp
```

This approach does not work because the created expression and variables are of type string while the correct types should be `<class 'pyeda.boolalg.expr.OrOp'>` for the expression and `<class 'pyeda.boolalg.expr.variables'>` for variables.

In the interactive mode we can do the above steps easily, but how can we build this expression in script mode using a boolean expression string with a dynamic number of variables sent from the frontend?

Answer (score 0):

pyEDA has a `expr()` function that converts text to an expression.
Here is how it works on your example.

```
>>> f = expr('( (A & B) | (C & ~D) )')

>>> f
Or(And(C, ~D), And(A, B))

>>> type(f)
<class 'pyeda.boolalg.expr.OrOp'>
```

Here is a link to more info.
[text to expression](https://pyeda.readthedocs.io/en/latest/expr.html#from-the-expr-function)